# Debt Snowball Function

Tags: javascript, function, google-apps-script

```
function DEBT_CALC() {
    let debts = [
        { title: "AMEX", interestRate: 0.14, minimumPayment: 52.55, balance: 510 },
        { title: "Chase", interestRate: 0.19, minimumPayment: 30, balance: 900 },
        { title: "US Bank", interestRate: 0.15, minimumPayment: 70, balance: 600 }
    ];

    let debtStrategy = "avalanche";
    let additionalPayment = 0;
    let months = 0;
    let totalInterestPaid = 0;
    let rollingMinimumPayment = 0;
    let overpaymentApplied = false; // Flag to track if overpayment has been applied in the current month

    function sortDebts() {
        if (debtStrategy === 'snowball') {
            debts.sort((a, b) => a.balance - b.balance);
        } else if (debtStrategy === 'avalanche') {
            debts.sort((a, b) => b.interestRate - a.interestRate);
        }
    }

    sortDebts();
    console.log("Initial Debt Order: " + debts.map(debt => debt.title).join(", "));

    while (debts.some(debt => debt.balance > 0)) {
        months++;
        let overpayment = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < debts.length; i++) {
            let debt = debts[i];

            if (debt.balance > 0) {
                let interest = debt.balance * (debt.interestRate / 12);
                totalInterestPaid += interest;
                debt.balance += interest;

                let payment = Math.min(debt.balance, debt.minimumPayment + additionalPayment + rollingMinimumPayment + overpayment);
                debt.balance -= payment;
                console.log(`\t Payment of $${payment.toFixed(2)} made to ${debt.title}`);

                if (debt.balance <= 0) {
                    console.log(`\t\t ${debt.title} is paid off`);
                    overpayment = (debt.minimumPayment + additionalPayment + overpayment) - payment;
                    rollingMinimumPayment += debt.minimumPayment;
                    debt.balance = 0;

                    if (overpayment > 0 && !overpaymentApplied) {
                        for (let j = 0; j < debts.length; j++) {
                            if (debts[j].balance > 0 && debts[j].title !== debt.title) {
                                console.log(`\t\t Overpayment of $${overpayment.toFixed(2)} from ${debt.title} applied to ${debts[j].title}`);
                                debts[j].balance = Math.max(debts[j].balance - overpayment, 0);
                                overpaymentApplied = true;
                                overpayment = 0;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    overpayment = (debt.minimumPayment + additionalPayment + overpayment) - payment;
                }
            }

            if (i == debts.length - 1) {
                overpaymentApplied = false; // Reset the flag for the next month
            }
        }

        console.log(`End of Month ${months}: ` + debts.map(debt => `${debt.title} balance = $${Math.max(debt.balance, 0).toFixed(2)}`).join(", "));
    }

    console.log(`Total Months to pay off: ${months}`);
    console.log(`Total Interest Paid: $${totalInterestPaid.toFixed(2)}`);
}
```

I doubt anyone is going to help with this, but I can't get this function right no matter how hard I try. The problem correctly is that in month 10 AMEX gets a higher payment for some reason because US bank gets paid off in the same month - so frustrating! I also haven't coded the additional payments yet..

Here's what I have and I'm so close but also so close to giving up... To explain, snowball means lowest balance debts get paid off first, and avalanche means the highest interest gets paid off first. After a debt is paid off, that minimum payment will get applied to the next debt in the sorted list (sorted by snowball or avalanche). An overpayment is simply when a debt gets paid too much and that overpayment will happen directly in that month, where a minimum payment gets applied into the next month!

Comment: This is javascript, not java - they are different languages.

Comment: @BIBOOunit1998X tag is javascript

Comment: *"I doubt anyone is going to help with this"* dont start asking a question like this. Second you need to clear up your question. I dont know what your issue is and how it differs to what youre actually receiving. You should look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then this - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Craicerjack Thank you, I'll read those and edit this post!

Comment: I don't understand what this means: "An overpayment is simply when a debt gets paid too much and that overpayment will happen directly in that month, where a minimum payment gets applied into the next month". Why would an overpayment occur, when your code uses Math.min() to ensure you don't pay more than the outstanding balance on any card?

Comment: @AndrewParks This is because I plan on having a display of a balance on each debt. I don't want a balance to show -$66. I want it to show $0, and that $66 goes towards the next payment. The minimum payment for that debt also goes towards the next debt

Comment: I'm not an accountant so don't use accounting terms to ask me questions about scripting because I don't care about them.

Comment: @Cooper I'm worried for you if you think you need to be an accountant to understand these terms! But hey I get you, I'm so lost in this code right now this was my final hope.

Comment: debtstratecy is undefined in sortDebts

Comment: debts is  undefined in sortDebts()

Comment: debtStrategy is not used in DEBT_CALC

Comment: @Cooper Thanks for your comment, when I'm home I'll take a look. That would be funny if that's why this doesn't work, but I know the order outputs to the console correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote it like this:

```
function sortDebts(debtStrategy,debts) {
  if (debtStrategy === 'snowball') {
    debts.sort((a, b) => a.balance - b.balance);
  } else if (debtStrategy === 'avalanche') {
    debts.sort((a, b) => b.interestRate - a.interestRate);
  }
}

function DEBT_CALC() {
  let debts = [
    { title: "AMEX", interestRate: 0.14, minimumPayment: 52.55, balance: 510 },
    { title: "Chase", interestRate: 0.19, minimumPayment: 30, balance: 900 },
    { title: "US Bank", interestRate: 0.15, minimumPayment: 70, balance: 600 }
  ];
  let debtStrategy = "avalanche";
  let additionalPayment = 0;
  let months = 0;
  let totalInterestPaid = 0;
  let rollingMinimumPayment = 0;
  let overpaymentApplied = false; // Flag to track if overpayment has been applied in the current month
  sortDebts(debtStrategy,debts);
  Logger.log("Initial Debt Order: " + debts.map(debt => debt.title).join(", "));

  while (debts.some(e => e.balance > 0)) {
    months++;
    let overpayment = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < debts.length; i++) {
      let d = debts[i];

      if (d.balance > 0) {
        let interest = d.balance * (d.interestRate / 12);
        totalInterestPaid += interest;
        d.balance += interest;

        let payment = Math.min(d.balance, d.minimumPayment + additionalPayment + rollingMinimumPayment + overpayment);
        d.balance -= payment;
        Logger.log(`\t Payment of $${payment.toFixed(2)} made to ${d.title}`);

        if (d.balance <= 0) {
          Logger.log(`\t\t ${d.title} is paid off`);
          overpayment = (d.minimumPayment + additionalPayment + overpayment) - payment;
          rollingMinimumPayment += d.minimumPayment;
          d.balance = 0;

          if (overpayment > 0 && !overpaymentApplied) {
            for (let j = 0; j < debts.length; j++) {
              if (debts[j].balance > 0 && debts[j].title !== d.title) {
                Logger.log(`\t\t Overpayment of $${overpayment.toFixed(2)} from ${d.title} applied to ${debts[j].title}`);
                debts[j].balance = Math.max(debts[j].balance - overpayment, 0);
                overpaymentApplied = true;
                overpayment = 0;
                break;
              }
            }
          }
        } else {
          overpayment = (d.minimumPayment + additionalPayment + overpayment) - payment;
        }
      }

      if (i == debts.length - 1) {
        overpaymentApplied = false; // Reset the flag for the next month
      }
    }

    Logger.log(`End of Month ${months}: ` + debts.map(debt => `${debt.title} balance = $${Math.max(debt.balance, 0).toFixed(2)}`).join(", "));
  }

  Logger.log(`Total Months to pay off: ${months}`);
  Logger.log(`Total Interest Paid: $${totalInterestPaid.toFixed(2)}`);
}
```

The Output:

```
Execution log
2:59:14 PM  Notice  Execution started
2:59:13 PM  Info    Initial Debt Order: Chase, US Bank, AMEX
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $30.00 made to Chase
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $70.00 made to US Bank
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $52.55 made to AMEX
2:59:13 PM  Info    End of Month 1: Chase balance = $884.25, US Bank balance = $537.50, AMEX balance = $463.40
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $30.00 made to Chase
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $70.00 made to US Bank
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $52.55 made to AMEX
2:59:13 PM  Info    End of Month 2: Chase balance = $868.25, US Bank balance = $474.22, AMEX balance = $416.26
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $30.00 made to Chase
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $70.00 made to US Bank
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $52.55 made to AMEX
2:59:13 PM  Info    End of Month 3: Chase balance = $852.00, US Bank balance = $410.15, AMEX balance = $368.56
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $30.00 made to Chase
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $70.00 made to US Bank
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $52.55 made to AMEX
2:59:13 PM  Info    End of Month 4: Chase balance = $835.49, US Bank balance = $345.27, AMEX balance = $320.31
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $30.00 made to Chase
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $70.00 made to US Bank
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $52.55 made to AMEX
2:59:13 PM  Info    End of Month 5: Chase balance = $818.72, US Bank balance = $279.59, AMEX balance = $271.50
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $30.00 made to Chase
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $70.00 made to US Bank
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $52.55 made to AMEX
2:59:13 PM  Info    End of Month 6: Chase balance = $801.68, US Bank balance = $213.08, AMEX balance = $222.12
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $30.00 made to Chase
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $70.00 made to US Bank
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $52.55 made to AMEX
2:59:13 PM  Info    End of Month 7: Chase balance = $784.37, US Bank balance = $145.75, AMEX balance = $172.16
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $30.00 made to Chase
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $70.00 made to US Bank
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $52.55 made to AMEX
2:59:13 PM  Info    End of Month 8: Chase balance = $766.79, US Bank balance = $77.57, AMEX balance = $121.62
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $30.00 made to Chase
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $70.00 made to US Bank
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $52.55 made to AMEX
2:59:13 PM  Info    End of Month 9: Chase balance = $748.93, US Bank balance = $8.54, AMEX balance = $70.49
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $30.00 made to Chase
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $8.65 made to US Bank
2:59:13 PM  Info             US Bank is paid off
2:59:13 PM  Info             Overpayment of $61.35 from US Bank applied to Chase
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $71.31 made to AMEX
2:59:13 PM  Info             AMEX is paid off
2:59:13 PM  Info    End of Month 10: Chase balance = $669.44, US Bank balance = $0.00, AMEX balance = $0.00
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $152.55 made to Chase
2:59:13 PM  Info    End of Month 11: Chase balance = $527.49, US Bank balance = $0.00, AMEX balance = $0.00
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $152.55 made to Chase
2:59:13 PM  Info    End of Month 12: Chase balance = $383.29, US Bank balance = $0.00, AMEX balance = $0.00
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $152.55 made to Chase
2:59:13 PM  Info    End of Month 13: Chase balance = $236.81, US Bank balance = $0.00, AMEX balance = $0.00
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $152.55 made to Chase
2:59:13 PM  Info    End of Month 14: Chase balance = $88.01, US Bank balance = $0.00, AMEX balance = $0.00
2:59:13 PM  Info         Payment of $89.40 made to Chase
2:59:13 PM  Info             Chase is paid off
2:59:13 PM  Info    End of Month 15: Chase balance = $0.00, US Bank balance = $0.00, AMEX balance = $0.00
2:59:13 PM  Info    Total Months to pay off: 15
2:59:13 PM  Info    Total Interest Paid: $233.86
2:59:16 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: No way thank you so much! The math is a little off so I'll have to figure that out but the function is finally doing what's intended! For reference I have no idea why AMEX is getting paid off in month 10 when it should have a 18.76 balance. but this is the closet i got it so thanks

Comment: It was actually fairly simple to debug

Comment: Fortunately the logic was essentially flawless

Comment: I got caught up in my own bias why I thought it wasn't working

Comment: Try using the debugger to single step through the process and you will probably be able to figure out the problem with the math.